# Intent put extra for whats app doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, whatsapp

I create an intent into whatsapp app that if I click the list of a phone number, it will open whatsapp and open the conversation if the number are exist in whatsapp. I succeed until open the conversation. The things that got me stuck is, my message in the intent put extra doesn't work. So the it doesn't show anything in the whatsapp text box.

Here is my code for intent :

```
rvListWa!!.addOnItemTouchListener(RecyclerItemClickListener(this@ShareFileActivity,
            RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener { view, position ->

        val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62"+tempDatas!![position].custHpWa
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is an example of the text that will be sended")
        startActivity(intent)

    }))
```

It already succeed into the open conversation in whatsapp, but not with the put extra.

Any solution of this problem ? as soon as possible.

Comment: try setting `intent.setType("text/plain");` to your intent

Comment: it doesn't work @KaranMer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT`

Try this

```
val msg = "This is going to be the message"
val url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=62"+tempDatas!![position].custHpWa + "&text="+msg
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.data = Uri.parse(url)
startActivity(intent)
```

or

Add `intent.setType("text/plain")`